# Fastest way to toggle array values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some facet filters in my site. The current implementation feels too slow.

Can anyone help me improve the speed?

Filters Object

```
{
   line1: {
     facet1: []
     facet2: []
     facet3: []
  }
}
```

Current function

```
 const toggleFilter = (productLine, facet, value) => () => {
        setFilters(oldFilters => ({ ...oldFilters,
            [productLine]: {
                ...oldFilters[productLine],
                [facet]: oldFilters[productLine][facet].includes(value) ?
                    oldFilters[productLine][facet].filter(v => v !== value) :
                    [...oldFilters[productLine][facet], value]
            }
        }))
    };
```

Would changing the type to array improve the speed?

Comment: Define "feels slow" - have you profiled this and seen that it is a bottleneck? Be wary of premature optimization

Comment: Is performance really an issue for you? Did you try to get some data via [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/time) first before you optimize prematurly. Also, please state a specific goal of improvement and what you can trade-off.